# Windows / ctypes issue with custom build

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ctypes

## EDIT (begin)

After spending time with @eryksun we dug really deep and found the underlying issue.  These two examples `fail1.py` and `fail2.py` have the same effect as the original lengthier example I posted.

It turns out the issue has to do with copying 4-byte C ints into an 8-byte stack location without zero'ing out the memory first, potentially leaving garbage in the upper 4 bytes.  This was confirmed using a debugger (again props to @eryksun).

This was one of those weird bugs (heisenbug) where you can add some printf statements then the bug doesn't exist any more.

#### the fix

> At the top ffi_prep_args on the line before argp = stack;, add a call
>   to memset(stack, 0, ecif->cif->bytes);. This will zero the entire
>   stack.

This is the location to fix:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.13/Modules/_ctypes/libffi_msvc/ffi.c#L47

#### fail1.py

```
import ctypes
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')

hStdout = kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11)
written = ctypes.c_ulong()
kernel32.WriteFile(hStdout, b'spam\n', 5, ctypes.byref(written), None)
```

#### fail2.py

```
import ctypes
import msvcrt
import sys
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')

hStdout = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(sys.stdout.fileno())
written = ctypes.c_ulong()
kernel32.WriteFile(hStdout, b'spam\n', 5, ctypes.byref(written), None)
```

## EDIT (end)

I built my own Python 2.7.13 for Windows because I'm using bindings I created to a 3rd party application which must be built with a specific build of Visual Studio 2012.
I started to code up some stuff using the "click" module and found an error when using click.echo with any kind of unicode echo.

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Mar 27 2017, 11:11:01) [MSC v.1700 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import click
>>> click.echo('Hello World')
Hello World
>>> click.echo(u'Hello World')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\eric\my_env\lib\site-packages\click\utils.py", line 259, in echo
    file.write(message)
  File "C:\Users\eric\my_env\lib\site-packages\click\_winconsole.py", line 180, in write
    return self._text_stream.write(x)
  File "C:\Users\eric\my_env\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 63, in write
    return io.TextIOWrapper.write(self, x)
  File "C:\Users\eric\my_env\lib\site-packages\click\_winconsole.py", line 164, in write
    raise OSError(self._get_error_message(GetLastError()))
OSError: Windows error 6
```

If I download and install the Python 2.7.13 64-bit installer I don't get this issue.  It echo's just fine.
I have looked into this a lot and am at a loss right now.
I'm not too familiar with Windows, Visual Studio, or ctypes.

I spent some time looking at the code path to produce the smallest file (without click) which demonstrates this problem (see below)
It produces the same "Windows error 6"... again, this works fine with the python installed from the 2.7.13 64 bit MSI installer.
Can someone share the process used to create the Windows installers?  Is this a manual process or is it automated?
Maybe I'm missing some important switch to msbuild or something.  Any help or ideas are appreciated.
I cannot use a downloaded copy of Python... it needs to be built with a specific version, update, patch, etc of Visual Studio.

All I did was

- clone cpython from github and checkout 2.7.13
- edit some xp stuff out of tk stuff to get it to compile on Windows Server 2003

  - In `externals\tk-8.5.15.0\win\Makefile.in` remove `ttkWinXPTheme.$(OBJEXT)` line
  - In `externals\tk-8.5.15.0\win\makefile.vc` remove `$(TMP_DIR)\ttkWinXPTheme.obj` line
  - In `externals\tk-8.5.15.0\win\ttkWinMonitor.c` remove 2 `TtkXPTheme_Init` lines

    - In `PCbuild\tcltk.props` change VC9 to VC11 at the bottom
- PCbuild\build.bat -e -p x64 "/p:PlatformToolset=v110"

After that I created an "install" by copying .exe, .pyd, .dll files, ran get-pip.py, then python -m pip install virtualenv, then virtualenv my_env, then activated it, then did a pip install click.
But with this stripped down version you don't need pip, virtualenv or click... just ctypes.
You could probably even build it without the -e switch to build.bat.

```
from ctypes import byref, POINTER, py_object, pythonapi, Structure, windll
from ctypes import c_char, c_char_p, c_int, c_ssize_t, c_ulong, c_void_p
c_ssize_p = POINTER(c_ssize_t)

kernel32 = windll.kernel32
STDOUT_HANDLE = kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11)

PyBUF_SIMPLE = 0
MAX_BYTES_WRITTEN = 32767

class Py_buffer(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('buf', c_void_p),
        ('obj', py_object),
        ('len', c_ssize_t),
        ('itemsize', c_ssize_t),
        ('readonly', c_int),
        ('ndim', c_int),
        ('format', c_char_p),
        ('shape', c_ssize_p),
        ('strides', c_ssize_p),
        ('suboffsets', c_ssize_p),
        ('internal', c_void_p)
    ]
    _fields_.insert(-1, ('smalltable', c_ssize_t * 2))

bites = u"Hello World".encode('utf-16-le')
bytes_to_be_written = len(bites)
buf = Py_buffer()
pythonapi.PyObject_GetBuffer(py_object(bites), byref(buf), PyBUF_SIMPLE)
buffer_type = c_char * buf.len
buf = buffer_type.from_address(buf.buf)
code_units_to_be_written = min(bytes_to_be_written, MAX_BYTES_WRITTEN) // 2
code_units_written = c_ulong()

kernel32.WriteConsoleW(STDOUT_HANDLE, buf, code_units_to_be_written, byref(code_units_written), None)
bytes_written = 2 * code_units_written.value

if bytes_written == 0 and bytes_to_be_written > 0:
    raise OSError('Windows error %s' % kernel32.GetLastError())
```

Comment: Change to using `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)`. Then for getting the last error use `ctypes.get_last_error()` and raise a properly formatted exception using `raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())`.

Comment: If you're still seeing it as a `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` (6), then the process `StandardOutput` isn't a valid console screen-buffer handle. Try to directly open a handle for the screen buffer using `hStdOut =  msvcrt.get_osfhandle(os.open('CONOUT$', os.O_RDWR))`.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun !!!
This worked, the question is why?  This is magic to me right now and I would appreciate an explanation.  What is wrong with my Python build vs. the one you get from the MSI installer?  It would be preferable to be able to "pip install click" and use it as opposed to forking/monkey patching/waiting for a pull request to get merged.  What assumptions does the current implementation make that I'm not fulfilling in my build?  How can I get my build to work with click out of the box?

Comment: Which suggestion worked? Better handling of the error or opening "CONOUT$" instead of using the `StandardOutput` handle? If it's the latter, what's the value returned by `GetStdHandle(-11)`?

Comment: The latter is what made the printing work.  First part is still in place too giving me better error messages.  With both the MSI installed python and my build `kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11)` always returns `32` yet the MSI works and my python errors out.  With the "CONOUT$" it seems to vary from run to run but is somewhere in the range of `224L` - `264L`

Comment: Another interesting thing is that with the MSI build I can call `kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11)`, print the result return value, then still call `msvcrt.get_osfhandle` and be able to print u"Hello World".  With my Python build adding that call to `kernel32.GetStdHandle` causes it to fail even if I never use the handle that is returned.  Just the act of executing that line causes what would be an otherwise working script to fail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139258/discussion-between-eric-frederich-and-eryksun).